# How to look up users email based on user name

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, sharepoint-email

I have a pair of fields, Project Manager Name and Project Manager Email.
Project Manager Name is a people picker field allowing the user to select a PM by display name when they create or edit a project.

I want to create a list workflow to look up the email address of the user selected in the Project Manager field and populate the Email field with that address.

Currently I have the following workflow published:

> Set PMMail to CurrentItem:ProjectManager
>
> Where  CurrentItem is Workflow lookup for user in Datasource: Current Item, Field: ProjectManager returning field as Email Address

The workflow contains no errors and publishes properly. It runs on item creation and completes but the Email field remains blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it. At least the following workflow is working in SharePoint 2013 on-prem.

I created a list called "get mail" with the columns

> Title -> single line of text
>
> Project Manager Name -> Person or Group Field
>
> Project Manager Email > single line of text

The workflow looks like this:

Select from actions "Set field in current item", then select the `Project Manager Email` column(1) and set it to the `currentitem`(2) and as sourcefield `Project Manager Name`(3). As return value there is the option `Email Address`(4).

[image]

That should be it. My output looks like this:

[image]

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks, you've confirmed my method is sound. There must be something going wrong at the profile level. I'll investigate further

Comment: You could check via central administration if there are entries for the email in your user properties.